# Calibration Expectation Decompostion

Tags: machine-learning, classification, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am reading a "Calibrated Structured Prediction by Kuleshov and Liang" [link](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2015/file/52d2752b150f9c35ccb6869cbf074e48-Paper.pdf).

> Calibration and sharpness. Given a forecaster $F : X → [0, 1]$, define $T(x) = \mathbb{E}[y| F(x)]$ to be the true probability of $y = 1$ given a that $x$ received a forecast $F(x)$. We can use $T$ to decompose the $l_2$ prediction loss as follows:
> $$
> \mathbb{E}[(y-F(x))^2] = \mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))^2] + \mathbb{E}[(T(x)-F(x))^2]=\text{var}[y]-\text{var}[T(x)]+ \mathbb{E}[(T(x)-F(x))^2]
> $$
> The first equality follows because $y−T(x)$ has expectation $0$ conditioned on $F(x)$, and the second equality follows from the variance decomposition of $y$ onto $F(x)$.

Trying to prove the above. What I have got so far.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(y-F(x))^2] & = \mathbb{E}[(y-T(x)+T(x)-F(x))^2] \\\\
& = \mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))^2]+ \mathbb{E}[(T(x)-F(x))^2]+
2\mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))(T(x)-F(x))]\\
\end{align}
$$

For the last term in above using law of total expectation,
conditioning on $F(x)$:

$$
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))(T(x)-F(x))]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))(T(x)-F(x))\vert F(x)]] 
\end{equation*}
$$

The second parenthesis is a function of $F(x)$ so can come out of conditioning.
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))(T(x)-F(x))]&=\mathbb{E}[(T(x)-F(x))\mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))\vert F(x)]]\\\\
& = \mathbb{E}[(T(x)-F(x))(T(x)-T(x))]=0
\end{align*}
$$
Which used the definition of $T(x)$.

So far we have:
$$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[(y-F(x))^2]=\mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))^2] + \mathbb{E}[(T(x)-F(x))^2]
\end{equation}
$$

However, I can not close the derivation by proving:
$$
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))^2]  =\text{var}[y]-\text{var}[T(x)]
\end{equation*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the key insight is that from the definition of conditional expectation it follows that
$$
\mathbb{E} [ y \mathbb{E} (y | F(x)) ] = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}(Y | F(x))^2 ]
$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))^2 ] &= \mathbb{E}[y^2] - 2
\mathbb{E} [ y \mathbb{E} (y | F(x)) ] + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(Y | F(x))^2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[y^2] -  \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(Y | F(x))^2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[y^2] - (\mathbb{E}[y])^2  - \left\{  \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(Y | F(x))^2] - (\mathbb{E}[y])^2 \right\} \\
&= \mathrm{var}[y] - \mathrm{var}[\mathbb{E}(y | F(x))] ,
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows from the law of total expectation.